# sqlite : Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()

Tags: php, database, php5, sqlite

I use a script that requires SQLITE,

On my previous host, it worked. On localhost it works. On my new dedicaced server, it doesn't.

I use PHP5 of course, you can access [phpinfo() of the server](http://gamer-certified.com/phpinfo.php).

Could you tell me what/how (apt-get?) to install correctly sqlite to avoid this fatal error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving indicates that the server doesn't have SQLite or its PHP modules installed. You can check the essential parts of the PHP environment by issuing `php -i | grep -i sqlite` on a terminal. It should result a list containing at least

```
PDO drivers => sqlite
pdo_sqlite
SQLite Library => <version_number>
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite support => enabled
```

You can install SQLite with `apt-get install sqlite3 php5-sqlite`, although there might sometimes arise issues with PDO drivers and they need to be fiddled with before everything is working.

Comment: i talked too fast, it seems to be working but it isn't ='(. I no longer have the unrecognize fucntion, but it still deosn't work What did you mean by need to be fiddled with before ?

Comment: IIRC I had to manually install some of the PDO extensions, like `apt-get install php-pear && pecl install pdo && pecl install pdo_sqlite` but that was a long time ago. Hopefully situation and support have improved in the mean time. If you still have other issues you might want to ask another question.